# Rrules and dayllght savings

Tags: javascript, node.js, dst, rrule

I'm using [rrule](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule) to create and store events in my database.

All was working until I found that my recurring events had an one hour difference past the 31st march.

In France, it's the day when we do a daylight saving time change.

Actually, my events are stored in a mongo database, with the start date and the duration of the event, + the eventuals rrules (all events aren't recurring events) like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8e4706703df43859aabbe7"),
    "duration" : 2879,
    "type" : "unavailability",
    "title" : "Weekend",
    "description" : "C'est le weekend",
    "rrules" : [ 
        {
            "until" : ISODate("2021-03-22T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "dtstart" : ISODate("2019-03-11T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "byweekday" : [ 
                {
                    "weekday" : 5
                }, 
                {
                    "weekday" : 6
                }
            ],
            "interval" : 1,
            "freq" : 2
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

When the frontend search for a date in the calendar, it will search with this args :

```
?from=2019-03-10T23:00:00.000Z&to=2019-03-17T23:00:00.000Z
```

It works well with this date, because no daylight savings are occuring in between. If I have this object :

```
normalizedDates = { from: 2019-03-10T23:00:00.000Z, to: 2019-03-17T23:00:00.000Z }
```

and this rule :

```
{ until: 2021-03-22T23:00:00.000Z,
  dtstart: 2019-03-11T23:00:00.000Z,
  byweekday: [ { weekday: 5 }, { weekday: 6 } ],
  interval: 1,
  freq: 2 }
```

Running :

```
const recurringDays = rruleSet.between(normalizedDates.from, normalizedDates.to)
```

shows, indeed :

```
recurringDays [ 2019-03-23T23:00:00.000Z ]
```

But if y use :

```
normalizedDates = { from: 2019-03-31T22:00:00.000Z, to: 2019-04-07T22:00:00.000Z }
```

Rrules returns :

```
recurringDays [ 2019-03-31T23:00:00.000Z, 2019-04-06T23:00:00.000Z ]
```

while I'm expecting :

```
recurringDays [ 2019-04-06T22:00:00.000Z ]
```

Do you know how I could handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a recurrence rule to observe daylight saving time for a particular time zone, then you *must* schedule using this time zone.  In your example, the schedule is based on UTC.

RRule provides [time zone support](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule#timezone-support).  You should use that, and specify `tzid: 'Europe/Paris'`.

Also, you might consider using the `toString` and `fromString` functions to work with iCalendar formatted strings, and store that in your MongoDB instance instead of serializing the RRule as JSON.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Do you think that this is the way to go ? https://gist.github.com/florianchevallier/ff196e25678e0be4d40a4fa06bc10049

And you definitively have a point for the `toString` and `fromString` functions